# Why is Source provider empty in Read method

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I have the following code in which I am initializing my variables and then calling the Read method of ISampleProvider manually. On checking, I saw that `sourceProvider.HasData(0)` is returning False and `sourceProvider.Read(buffer,offset,count)` is returning 0 despite `sourceProvider` being initialzed before the call.

```
    public void init(AudioFileReader sourceProvider, int cutOffFreq,float oldRMS)
    {
        this.sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
        this.cutOffFreq = cutOffFreq;

        filter_LowPass();            

        //Reading filtered bytes
        float []buff = new float[sourceProvider.Length];

        float sum=0;

        int r = Read(buff, 0, (int)sourceProvider.Length)/2;

        MessageBox.Show("Read: " + r);  Here this value is being shown 0
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            sum += buff[i] * buff[i];

        sum = (float)Math.Sqrt(sum / (float)r);
        MessageBox.Show("sum: " + sum);   //Output is coming NaN
        gain = (float)(oldRMS / sum);
        MessageBox.Show("Gain: " + gain); //Output is coming NaN
    }

    private void filter_LowPass()
    {
        channels = sourceProvider.WaveFormat.Channels;
        filters = new BiQuadFilter[channels];

        for (int n = 0; n < channels; n++)
            if (filters[n] == null)
                filters[n] = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
            else
                filters[n].SetLowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int samplesRead = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        MessageBox.Show("Inside read: " + samplesRead); //Output is coming 0
        MessageBox.Show("Source Provider: " + sourceProvider.HasData(0)); //Output is coming False

        for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
            buffer[offset + i] = gain * filters[(i % channels)].Transform(buffer[offset + i]);

        return samplesRead;
    }
```

My problem is coming when I am calling the Read method..the parameters buff,offset and count are correctly given

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Sorry. Can u help me with the problem I am facing?

Comment: as `init` holds the only write usage, do you call it before calling `Read`? could you possibly create a short example that shows a null-reference exception?

Comment: what is the actual value of `sourceProvider.Length`?

Comment: Sourceprovider does not have a null value